How can I implement few checkboxes in a Django Form?
I was given a task to create a recipe website. A user can add a recipe. They have to choose a category (categories). One recipe can belong to one category or to several. I am inheriting my Form from ModelForm. Here's the code for it:
class RecipeForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Recipe
        fields = ['title', 'description', 'ingredients', 'cooking_steps', 'time', 'calories', 'portions', 'image', 'categories']
        widgets = {
            'title' : TextInput(attrs={'class' : 'create_recipe_title', 'placeholder' : 'Enter a title...' }),
            'description' : TextInput(attrs={'class' : 'create_recipe_description', 'placeholder' : 'Enter a short description...' }),
            'ingredients' : Textarea(attrs={'class' : 'create_recipe_ingredients', 'placeholder' : 'Your ingredients...', 'disabled' : True }),
            'time' : NumberInput(attrs={'class' : 'create_recipe_time', 'placeholder' : 'Cooking time...' }),
            'calories' : NumberInput(attrs={'class' : 'create_recipe_calories', 'placeholder' : 'Calories...' }),
            'portions' : NumberInput(attrs={'class' : 'create_recipe_portions', 'placeholder' : 'Portions...' }),
            'image' : FileInput(attrs={'class' : 'create_recipe_image'}),
            'cooking_steps' : Textarea(attrs={'class' : 'create_recipe_cooking_steps', 'placeholder' : 'Describe the cooking process...' }),
            'categories' : SelectMultiple(choices=[(1, 'Food'), (2, 'Drinks'), (3, 'Hot'), (4, 'Cold'), (5, 'Breakfast'), (6, 'Lunch'), (7, 'Dinner'), (8, 'Baked'), (9, 'Soups'), (10, 'Salads'), (11, 'Pizza and pasta'), (12, 'Sauces'),(13, 'Portugal'), (14, 'Italy'), (15, 'France'), (16, 'Japan'), (17, 'Chine'), (18, 'Georgia'), (19, 'Armenia'), (20, 'Mexico'), (21, 'Africa'), (22, 'Dietary'), (23, 'Sugar free'), (24, 'Gluten and lactose free')])
                 }

However, it doesn't work like this. It doesn't show any checkboxes at all. I am sure I am doing all the rest right. But anyway, the code for my model:
class Recipe(Model):
    title         = CharField(max_length=20)
    description   = CharField(max_length=100)
    ingredients   = CharField(max_length=200)
    cooking_steps = CharField(max_length=2000)
    time          = IntegerField()
    calories      = IntegerField()
    portions      = IntegerField()
    image         = ImageField(upload_to='static/recipes_photos')
    author        = ForeignKey(User, on_delete=CASCADE)
    rating        = IntegerField(default=0)
    categories    = ManyToManyField(Category, blank=False)
    created       = DateField(auto_now_add=True)
    last_updated  = DateField(auto_now_add=True)
    saved_by      = ManyToManyField(User, related_name='recipe_saved_by')
    left_reaction = ManyToManyField(User, related_name='recipe_left_reaction')

    recipes       = RecipeManager()
    objects       = Manager()

and my view:
class AddRecipe(View):
    template_name = 'myapp/addrecipe.html'

    def get(self, request):
        context = {'add_recipe_form' : RecipeForm(),
                   'add_ingredient_form' : IngredientForm()}
        return render(request, self.template_name, context=context)
    
    def post(self, request):
        form = ArticleForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            recipe = form.save(commit=False)
            recipe.author = request.user
            recipe.save()        
            return redirect('recipe', recipe.pk)
        context = {'add_article_form' : form}
        return render(request, self.template_name , context=context)

Here's my template code:
         <div class='right'>
             {{ add_recipe_form.cooking_steps }}
             {{ add_recipe_form.image }}
             {{ add_recipe_form.categories }}
         </div>
     </form>

And what I see on a web:

What am I doing wrong?

Please add what bug you're encountering :)

@user20223018 there's no bug, it just doesn't work as expected. I want to see many checkboxes , but eventually there's nothing on a web

That is because you are using ModelForm and doing so sets the categories field like so:
categories = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(queryset=Category.objects.all())

Thus, if you have no Category records, the QuerySet is empty and so are the choices.
On the other hand, your mistake is trying to override values at the widget level, while the field remains untouched. What you want is to override the field itself:
class RecipeForm(forms.ModelForm):
    categories = forms.MultipleChoiceField(
        choices=[
            (1, "Food"),
            (2, "Drinks"),
            (3, "Hot"),
            (4, "Cold"),
            (5, "Breakfast"),
            (6, "Lunch"),
            (7, "Dinner"),
            (8, "Выпечка и десерты"),
            (9, "Soups"),
            (10, "Salads"),
            (11, "Pizza and pasta"),
            (12, "Sauces"),
            (13, "Portugal"),
            (14, "Italy"),
            (15, "France"),
            (16, "Japan"),
            (17, "Chine"),
            (18, "Georgia"),
            (19, "Armenia"),
            (20, "Mexico"),
            (21, "Africa"),
            (22, "Dietary"),
            (23, "Sugar free"),
            (24, "Gluten and lactose free"),
        ]
    )

    class Meta:
        model = Recipe
        fields = [
            ...
        ]
        widgets = {
            ...
        }

You do not need to configure the categories MultipleChoiceField widget, since it defaults to SelectMultiple.
P.S.
Seems that I missed part of your question. To transform into checkboxes you do need to configure widgets:
class RecipeForm(forms.ModelForm):
    categories = forms.MultipleChoiceField(
        widget=forms.widgets.CheckboxSelectMultiple(),
        choices=[...],
    )
    ...


still doesn't work(

@dasEgo try to render it with no styling, although i am pretty sure that is not the issue. You can also remove categories from fields and widgets. those are the only things I think of at the moment.
